# How do I sort by a condition, then make the top result of the first the top of a different sort?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, collections

So i was wondering if I could sort

```
sortTarget = storeList
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.edited_date ?? x.created_date)
    .Select(y => new SortTarget { Id = y.id, store = y.store})
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

and then else where, i have this other sort going on:

```
var list = storeList
    .OrderBy(y => y.id)
    .ThenBy(z => z.store)
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(take);
```

but i want the top result to be the earlier sort target, with the subsequent results being the as-is results of the second sort. Is it possible to do this without explicitly combining the results? A single chain command.

I know that I can easily add the results of the first and then add the results of the second in separate statements, and not forgetting to remove the top result from the second call. I was wondering if it was possible without tampering with the collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a "conditional" sort:

```
var list = storeList
    .OrderByDescending(y => y.id == sortTarget.Id)
    .ThenBy(y => y.id)
    .ThenBy(z => z.store)
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(take);
```

`OrderByDescending` because a `true` is *greater than* a `false`